# Install development app version alongside production on same iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I have an app that's currently in the AppStore which I keep on my phone to show users and others who might be interested. At the same time I'm developing the next version of the app on the same phone. I would love to be able to have the two apps installed on the same device side-by-side.

What is the prescribed / least hacky way of making that happen? Is this possible at all? Ideally this would be as automated as possible with no manual renaming required before each deployment.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: With slight edits this is a real question that helped me a lot. The answer given by Alex Terente below works well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible you just have to sign the development app with a different app id.

For example:
if you have in store `com.myCompany.myWonderfulApp` 
use for dev `com.myCompany.myWonderfulAppDevelopment`

Comment: Would you recommend just renaming the bundle identifier until I'm ready to submit or should I perhaps create separate schemes for it (not sure you can customize the bundle id through a scheme though).

Comment: An update: the workaround you recommended does seem to enable deployment of both apps side-by-side, however xcode doesn't seem to be any longer able to launch the development app on my device. The error message is: Could not launch "My App" failed to get the task for process 123 (or some other process number). Is this to be expected?

Comment: No is not try to restart the device

Comment: Rebooting fixed that problem, thanks!

Comment: Smoothest solution for me: Under Target->Build Settings->Product Name, define separate names for "Debug" and "Release". By default the app id is generated from this product name, so you'll get the same effect of Alex's answer. Then I define 2 schemes, one with "Debug" for "Build Configuration" and one with "Release". Presto! Two apps on the phone, and switch between Schemes to choose which one you're building.

Comment: @Stan But what should I do with the provisioning profile. It says that it doesn't match the bundle identifier. I want to use the same provisioning profile since my app uses push notifications.

Comment: @roi.holtzman Hmm, I don't use push notifications so my Debug doesn't have a provisioning profile. This would also apply to Alex's answer, it seems. Could you create another provisioning profile for the debug, complete with it's own bundle identifier?

Comment: Any luck with this @roi.holtzman ? Trying to set this up as well